# Android: I want to monitor the outgoing sms

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android application, I want to monitor the incoming/outgoing sms by using a BroadcastReceiver, but the BroadcastReceiver only detects incoming sms. Is there any intent filter which can monitor the outgoing sms?

Here is my code.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT");           
context.registerReceiver(smsListner, filter);
```